# External Tables - Replace comma with dot in numbers

Tags: oracle

How can I replace a comma with a dot directly from the external table?

I have a CSV with that format:

> aaa;12345.67;bbbbbb
>
> ccc;23132;eeeee

Sometimes someone puts a line like that:

> ddd;1111,22;fff

```
CREATE TABLE MYTAB_EXT
  (
    "TX1"         VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "VAL1"  NUMBER(13,3),
    "TX2"   VARCHAR2(20)
  )
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXT_TABLES_FOO" ACCESS 
PARAMETERS ( 
      records delimited BY newline 
      SKIP 1 
      fields terminated BY ';' LRTRIM
      missing field VALUES are NULL ( 
          TX1 , 
          VAL1 , 
          TX2) 
          ) LOCATION ( 'MYTAB.csv' )
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is 'sometimes' - you shouldn't be expected to deal with inconsistent data. While it's simple to replace commas with periods, one day someone might send 123,456.78 which will then break. Or, indeed, 123.456,78. Even without both symbols, if you get either 1,234 or 1.234, how do you know if you're supposed to interpret as 1234 (treating as group separator) or 1.234 (treating as decimal separator)?

Comment: True, absolutely correct.
In a previous work we had a validation before (via SH) OR after the external table (via stored procedures or views). Here is not possible...

Comment: Why isn't it possible - can't you use a preprocessor directive? To replace the commas, even if it can't really validate?

Comment: We're going a bit OT, but to clarify. 
The ETL is a bit poor on this project.
The user downloads a template.csv, they edit it (with excel I presume?), they upload it back and the php does only 3 things: 1) moves the csv into the exTable folder (without any validation); 2) runs the package wich processes everything; 3) handle any exception from the package (alert for the user, email with stacktrace to us).
My question is about the possibility  to replace or not a character from there; any other road would been considered (here) a develop/refactoring and not a quickFix.

Comment: OK, so you can't touch the PHP at all? Does adding a separate preprocessor script count as development too?